# What makes "SqlMethods" Methods Work?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Simply put, what makes a method like `SqlMethods.DateDiffDay` work?

The method signature looks like this:

```
public static int DateDiffDay(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);
```

So what's going on inside (or outside via some magic) that makes this work:

```
var query = from a in db.TableA
            group a by SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(a.Start, a.End) into g
            select g.Key;
```

...and why would hiding it within my own method make it fail (not that I'm trying to do this for any reason, just trying to understand it better):

```
var query = from a in db.TableA
            group a by MyOwnDateDiffDay(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) into g
            select g.Key;

public static int MyOwnDateDiffDay(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(startDate, endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simply: the parsing engine, when looking at the expression-tree, is hard-coded to spot those methods and interpret them in a specific way in TSQL. It never actually *calls* the method - which is why your `MyOwnDateDiffDay` fails - it isn't programmed to spot `MyOwnDateDiffDay`.

You can do this to a *small* degree in your own code by using the `[Function(...)]` code that normally encapsulates UDFs for L2S - for example, here is a cheeky way of wrapping up the `NEWID` inbuilt SQL-Server function:

```
partial class MyDataContext
{
     [Function(Name="NEWID", IsComposable=true)] 
     public Guid Random() 
     { // to prove not used by our C# code... 
         throw new NotImplementedException(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for some clues for a cleaner way to replace the UDF solution. I was hoping this wouldn't be the answer, but at the same time kind of expected it to be. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

Using the LINQ expression `group x by y` actually calls (by name) `GroupBy` on the source. If the source implements `IEnumerable`, this would be one common method that is called, and which accepts an arbitrary function from the source type to some key value:

- [`Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx)

Some enumerable classes (such as the LINQ to SQL classes) do not only implement `IEnumerable<T>` but also `IQueryable<T>`. This means that the following method is also available:

- [`Queryable.GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534492.aspx)

Here, the method receives an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) which can be parsed. In the case of LINQ to SQL, the presence of `SqlMethods.*` is detected and, rather than executing the function, it is translated to the corresponding SQL Server operation and performed on the SQL Server (in your case, it's [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)).